# Change reset password url in Magento

Tags: php, reactjs, magento, magento2

I am using Magento with React (in the front-end). When a customer sends an email to reset the password it redirects to the Luma store, I want to be able to change that redirect link with my front-end link. How can I do that, should I make a change in the Magento code, or can be done in Admin Pagel? I try to change it in Admin Panel but it doesn't works.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.